# How to combine 3 select lists into a single input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 3 select lists for date of birth (one for day, month and year).

I need to have the selected options of these lists to be outputted into an input text field which will be hidden on the page.

```
   <SELECT class="combine" id ="date" name = "dd"></SELECT>
   <SELECT class="combine" id ="month" name = "mm"></SELECT>
   <SELECT class="combine" id ="year" name = "yyyy" ></SELECT>

   <input type="text" id="DOB" name="Dob" value="" />
```

Ideally i would like these to parse into a variable that can then be turned into a string and output into the hidden input text field.

A second part of this would be to change the month to be numberical values in the data that is sent to the hidden input field. This all needs to be done onChange basis not click.

Unfortunately, im a relative newbie to js and jquery so appreciate all your help on this.

Edit to add the Js file code that is controlling the date....

```
/***********************************************
* Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
* This notice MUST stay intact for use
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ 
  for this script  and more
* WARNING -------------------------------------------------------!-
* This javascript has been modified by *bdhacker* for real life use
* ishafiul@gmail.com
* http://bdhacker.wordpress.com
***********************************************/

var monthtext=   ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

function date_populate(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
    var today=new Date();
    var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
    var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
    var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
    for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
    dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i+1, i+1)
    dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(),       today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
   for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
   monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
   monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new      Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month

   var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
   for (var y=0; y<100; y++){
    yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
    thisyear-=1
   }
   yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(),    today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, add `onchange` event listeners to the `select` tags as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combine').on('change', function(){
        var date = $('#date').val() + '/' + $('#month').val() + '/' + $('#year').val();
        $('#DOB').val(date);
    });
})
```

See it working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d64ywctz/).

Comment: The only  issue i have is, when you edit an element, the date that is returned is of today's date and not the one that was previously entered, although the hidden input displays the correct date.  For example, I have an element that has a date of 03/03/2015 and when you go into this page to edit the date, the date shown on page load is today's date and not 03/03/2015

Comment: Anyone able to help in that when you have already submitted an entry into this form and then go back in to edit it, the dates on the select list display the current date whereas the the date dispplayed in the input field is the date that was previously entered. The dates on the select list need to match the date previosuly selected.  I am not too bothered about showing today's date as it could revert back to the first available date in the form on page load if no previous dates have been entered.